# How to do this with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have two conditions that need to be met to do specific things with mod_rewrite:

- admin.something.com should go to something.com/admin (as should something.com/admin)
- anythingelse.something.com should go to something.com/index.php?school=anythingelse, as should something.com/anythingelse

I assume(/hope) this is pretty simple, but I have absolutely no knowledge of mod_rewrite. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something to this effect

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin.something.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://something.com/admin [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^something.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://something.com/index.php?school=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.something\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^something.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?school=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.something\.com
RewriteRule .* http://something.com/admin [L,R=301]
```

I'd do redirect from subdomain.something.com to something.com/index.php?school=subdomain right in the php code, e.g.

```
header('Location: something.com/index.php?school='.$retreived_from_http_host_subdomain);
```

since I don't know how to get domain name within `RewriteRule` (maybe someone would post the answer here)